# POST jQuery array to Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, django, json

I'm trying to POST a jQuery array of simple numbers to Django, and I really can't make it work. I need a little help on this. I'm getting an Http 500 with the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /edit_lists/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jabez/.virtualenvs/hackernews/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/home/jabez/.virtualenvs/hackernews/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 106, in process_response
    if response.status_code == 404:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Here's my code:

#### JavaScript

```
    $('.btn-group').find('#mark_as_done').on('click', function() {
    var tasks = grab_selected();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/edit_lists/',
        data: {'tasks': tasks},
    });
});

function grab_selected() {
    var tasks = [];
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        tasks.push(this.id);
    });
    return tasks;
}
```

#### views.py

```
def edit_lists(request):
tasks = request.POST.getlist('tasks')
return tasks
```

#### urls.py

```
url(r'^edit_lists/$', 'todo.views.edit_lists', name='edit_lists')
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can try to use `tasks[]` instead of `tasks` as parameter when sending via ajax. Example:

```
$('.btn-group').find('#mark_as_done').on('click', function() {
    var tasks = grab_selected();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/edit_lists/',
        data: {'tasks[]': tasks},
    });
});
```

Another thing is you are simply returning `return tasks` in `edit_lists()` view, you have return a `HttpResponse` instance or use shortcut like `render`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def edit_lists(request):
    tasks = request.POST.getlist('tasks[]')
    return HttpResponse('Success')
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: it worked now :). I can't believe the answer was so simple. thank you very much!

Comment: How come you are sending tasks[] from ajax and able to retrieve via tasks variable. I tried in one of my example. I am getting empty list in django view. If I use request.POST.getlist('tasks[]') and if list in ajax is ['1','2'] then I am getting [u'1',u'2'] in django view.

Comment: @Pawan hmm pretty sure I tested when I gave the answer 1.5 years ago, maybe things were different back then. I will update my answer then, cheers!

Comment: Even if you send list by variable named tasks , then jQuery POST's arrays with the [] suffix because PHP and some web frameworks understand that convention, and re-build the array on the server-side for you automatically. Django doesn't work that way , but we can access the data via tasks[]

Comment: `selected = request.GET.getlist[‌​‌​'selected[]'] TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` I get this error...I have an array of stings like ["one","two","three"‌​‌​] and am using a GET request...

Comment: @nidHi it should be `selected = request.GET.getlist(​‌​‌​'selected[]')` (notice the brackets) since it's a method, not a dictionary

Comment: @HieuNguyen... Thank you for pointing that out... I completely missed out on the brackets...

Comment: From my tests, 'request.POST.get('tasks')' actually returns a list with only one element, which is a string consisting of all ids separated by commas. Is it correct?

Answer (score 12):

You can try to use `JSON.stringify()` method instead of tasks as parameter when sending via Ajax.

Here's the array data on my consol

[image]

Then send Array data by ajax

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/user/Survey-Design/",
     headers: {
         'Authorization': "Token " + localStorage.access_token
     },
     data: {
         'arr': JSON.stringify(arr)
     },
     success: function(result) {
         alert('Data Has been saved')
     }
 });
```

In views.py:

```
 def create(self,request):
     array_data = request.POST['arr']
     data = json.loads(array_data)
     print(data)
     return HttpResponse('Success')
```

Finally, show print(data) on terminal

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly with AJAZ > Django. Thanks.