# Why can't I post relatively complex JS objects to my Django view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, post

Using Django 1.5.5, I am trying to post a JS object to my view using `$.post`.

#### JavaScript

```js
var oDatas = { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $.cookie('csrftoken') };
oDatas['2'] = [ '4', '8', '15', '16', '23', '42' ];
$.post('/my/ajax/url/', oDatas)
    .done(function(oResponse, sStatus, oXHR) {
        // Handling successful request
    })
    .fail(function(oXHR, sStatus, sErrorThrown) {
        // Handling failed request
    });
```

#### View

```py
@require_AJAX
@require_POST
def get_bacon(request):
    datas = request.POST
    print datas
    response = HttpResponse('asdf', status=200)
    return response
```

#### Output

```
<QueryDict: {u'2[]': [u'4', u'8', u'15', u'16', u'23', u'42'],
             u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'B4micC9PgcT5jCP0WLef0ZLY9DICuH8Z']}>
```

Note the key is actually `'2[]'`.

#### Question

It does work fine with `oDatas['2'] = 'foobar';`. What am I missing ?

---

#### Related SO answer

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18046286/1824222

> You can try to use tasks[] instead of tasks as parameter when sending via ajax

In my case use `'2[]'` as key for my datas. It does sound gross though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured what I was struggling with was. The `request.POST` is here a QueryDict object. Django (1.5.5), flatten any relatively *complex* - read *nested* - JS object.

```py
datas = dict(request.POST.iterlists())
datas.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken')
```

Note that I use `iterlists` only because my QueryDict object contains lists. Use `iteritems` otherwise.

The `datas` dictionary is then a Python dict as such:

```py
{ 'foods[joe][]':   [ 'bacon', 'chicken', ],
  'foods[clara][]': [ 'lettuce', 'yogurt', 'oreo', ], }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing it via the `body` attribute. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body)

```
def get_bacon(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        datas = request.body
    else: 
        datas = request.POST
    print datas
    response = HttpResponse('asdf', status=200)
    return response
```

You might have to parse the json object as such:

```
import json

def get_bacon(request):
    datas = json.loads(request.body)
```

Edit:
Sorry I forgot to mention you'll have to stringify your data in the ajax call.

```
var oDatas = { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $.cookie('csrftoken') };
oDatas['2'] = [ '4', '8', '15', '16', '23', '42' ];
$.post('/my/ajax/url/', JSON.stringify(oDatas))
    .done(function(oResponse, sStatus, oXHR) {
        // Handling successful request
    })
    .fail(function(oXHR, sStatus, sErrorThrown) {
        // Handling failed request
    });
```

Comment: The `request.body` returns a stringified object with escaped characters. And when I pass it to `json.loads`, I get `ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 - line 1 column 117 (char 1 - 116)`.

Comment: Ah, that's much cleaner than my solution. I wonder if ```request.POST.getlist(key)``` would work for you.

Comment: Is it ? Altering my JS object keys and adding a set of braces per level of depth looks very dirty to me.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't look at the linked answer. I just saw that you had an answer and it was by using '2[]' for the key.

Comment: Yeah that's it. But my actual `oDatas` isn't exactly as *simple* as the one described in my original post (it's in fact an object containing my CSRF token and an other object). And having `'foo[bar][]'` as key for my  Python dictonary isn't very handy to work with (the `bar` part correspond to all the keys of the object within the parent object I am posting. Don't know if that's clear enough, english isn't my mother tongue.

Comment: It just seems that Django prevent posting nested objects with AJAX. So it flattens the object and gives a simple Python dictionary. Keys therefore contain sub keys as such: `food[bacon][]`, `food[oreo][]` for, say, a object containing lists of recipes using different foods. Hope that's more clear now.

Comment: Then do what I listed in my answer. Call ```JSON.stringify``` on ```oDatas``` and then parse the JSON out in the view. That'll allow you to make as complex of a object as you want.

Comment: Doesn't work as stated above, c/p for convenience: `ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 - line 1 column 117 (char 1 - 116)`.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was before I said to do the stringify. Or is it giving you the same result passing oDatas and stringified oDatas in the POST?

Comment: I've added an answer.